# How to write Thread application in DO file of Model-sim 10.5c using TCL?

Tags: tcl, fpga, modelsim, intel-fpga

I have a FPGA logic, which contains the Logic-A and Logic-B functionalities.
I need to create two threads in DO file (TCL) for driving the data to the FPGA Inputs.

Thread 1: FPGA Inputs.

```
'#sim:/tb_uut/uut/DATA_IN 1F 00'
```

Thread 2: Provide the inputs to B_IN in Logic B, when A_IN is high, otherwise ignore B_IN.

```
    '#If { [examine sim:/tb_uut/Logic_B/A_IN]==1} { #sim:/tb_uut/Logic_B/B_IN 1 0 #}'
```

Here I need to monitor the value of the A_IN until getting high.
I am able to drive the B_in during post synthesis simulations by accessing B_IN.
I am unable to create two different threads for continuous monitoring of A_IN and driving DATA_IN to FPGA.

How to create the thread in TCL?

Whether threads will be supporting in modelsim 10.5c or not?

How to independently provide the Inputs using DO and VHDL files ?

Comment: Did any one facing any challenges in understanding the above question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use TCL threads in ModelSim, it's not supported. This is also not the way to do things in parallel for a VHDL simulation.

Instead, register a TCL callback which executes when the signal you are monitoring changes. You can continue to drive the other signal while monitoring first one. Refer to the "when" command in the [ModelSim Command Reference Manual](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/136364-modelsim-me-10-4c-command-reference-manual-for-libero-soc-v11-7).

I've constructed this example which demonstrates how you can use the "when" command in a ModelSim TCL script.

In the TCL script:

```tcl
when -label MyLabel {A_IN == '1'} {
  echo "Hello from TCL at $now ns"
}

run -all
```

The VHDL process:

```vhd
process
begin

  wait for 10 ns;
  A_IN <= '1';
  wait for 10 ns;
  A_IN <= '0';
  wait for 10 ns;
  A_IN <= '1';
  wait for 10 ns;
  A_IN <= '0';

  report "VHDL simulation finished";
  finish;

end process;
```

The output to the ModelSim console after we run the TCL script:

```text
VSIM 1> do run.do
# Hello from TCL at 10 ns
# Hello from TCL at 30 ns
# ** Note: VHDL simulation finished
#    Time: 40 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /ent
```

Comment: I am performing the Gatelevel Simulations for the sample design mentioned in the Image.
I have FPGA inputs  DATA_IN1, DATA_IN2 and DATA_IN3 and Outputs .
A_IN and B_IN are the gatelevel netlist between LOGIC_A  and LOGIC_B insdie my FPGA Logic.

I need to montior the output C_OUT when A_IN and B_IN are high, If equal, I need to change any of it to different value, as mentioned below

Comment: Here I am changing above I am geetting the error as "No objects found matching '$'."

How  do I monitor the value  of C_OUT during run time of 50ns, either high or low ?

Comment: ```set A_IN_test [examine sim:/FGPA_DESIGN/LOGIC_B/A_IN]  
    set B_IN_test [examine sim:/FGPA_DESIGN/LOGIC_B/B_IN]
    when -label Mylabel {$A_IN_test == 1 &&  $B_IN_test == 1} {
 force -freeze sim:/FGPA_DESIGN/LOGIC_B/B_IN 1 0 -cancel 50ns
    run -50ns
    if {[examine sim:/FGPA_DESIGN/LOGIC_B/C_OUT]== 1} { # need to to check C_OUT during run time of 50ns.`
  puts "B_IN changed to low"
  } 
}
 run -all```